# A three-input NAND gate is to be used as an inverter. Which one of the following measures will achieve better results?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, inverter, boolean-algebra

1. The two inputs not used are kept open
2. The two inputs not used are connected to ground (0 level)
3. The two inputs not used are connected to logic supply (1 level)
4. None of the above

I get that we can either connect them to ground or make them both high, and the output will remain the same. But connecting to high seems to be a better alternative. Why is it so?

Comment: Do the truth table.

Comment: Can they, though? [be connected to ground] What about other options, like tying inputs in common -- I take it this is a multiple-choice with only these shown?

Comment: None of the above would be my answer by a short neck.

Comment: @Andyaka I think the words *BETTER results* in the question makes one of the first three choices acceptable.

Comment: What technology is the NAND gate? TTL and CMOS might have different answers, and there are other technologies as well. 'Better' might need to be better defined. There's a difference between some of the answers for whether the gate works at all, hardly a 'better' question.

Comment: Only one option will deliver the expected result. There’s no option for connecting all the inputs together which would be a valid solution. As the ratman suggests, look at the truth table - it is the source of truth!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat The truth table does not tell you how an open input gets interpreted.  That's a matter of how the logic is mapped to electronics.

Comment: @user107063 We do not know the context of a multiple-choice question.  Reading more into it than is required is difficult from an engineering perspective.  So within that context, the truth table with the other choices will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the technology.  Answers for TTL and CMOS are slightly different, and there are quite a few others as well.  You also don't specify an objective for what you call "better".

Short of the technology in question, the only facet of the answer you can specify is that you need to connect unused inputs either to something interpreted as logical 1 (or the output will get fixed at logical 1 irrespective of the input) or to the input to be inverted.

Which kind of input that is interpreted as logic 1 will be best depends on the technology.  Some will take VCC directly, some may warrant a resistor for protection against transient behavior.  While I wouldn't fancy it, TTL logic would not mind open pins a lot, either.

Comment: Lucky it is just a multiple choice question!